# Same login for Multiple apps using CookieAuthentication

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I have several MVC 4 apps in the same server that all utilize microsoft identity and share the same database.  The machinekey in the web config is the same for all of them and they all have the same ConfigureAuth method with the same cookie name and domain.  Thus if one is logged into one app they are authorized on the others.  I would like to consolidate my login logic to one app and have all the other apps redirected to the same app for authentication.  I know this can be done in Forms Authentication in the web.config file, but I cannot find how to do this using the Cookies Authentication.  I have tried to change the pathstring in this line:  LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),  but it will always add the base as the directory of the app and will not redirect to another app in the server.  Here is my code, its pretty much out of the box.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
\\I have tried to change the pathstring but if I use something besides a '/' I get an error.  
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
          
            
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
               
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            CookieDomain = ".mydomain.com",
            CookieName = "Mycookie"
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  The calling app needs the following code to be added to the ConfigAuth

```
//.... as above
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                **OnApplyRedirect= MainLogin**
            },
//..... as above

 private void MainLogin(CookieApplyRedirectContext obj)
    {
          obj.Response.Redirect("https://[AuthAppAddress]/Account/Login?ReturnURL=" + obj.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri); 
    }
```

the Authorizing app needs the following code to the account controller in order to distinguish between calls from its own app or other apps:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            if (returnUrl.StartsWith("https://"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```